# How to find the current foreground activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to find the current foreground activity in android.I am not using ActivityGroup.

Comment: Are you running in a Service?

Comment: From where you want to get current activity is it Service or any activity or else ?.Clarify your question

Comment: Yes i am running in a service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that it you need to look at the [ActivityManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html).  I took a brief look at the docs and this is what I came up with.

There's a function:

```
public List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> getRunningTasks (int maxNum)
```

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29):

Return a list of the tasks that are currently running, with the most recent being first and older ones after in order. Note that "running" does not mean any of the task's code is currently loaded or activity -- the task may have been frozen by the system, so that it can be restarted in its previous state when next brought to the foreground.

My thought would be if you pass in `maxNum=1`, it should give you the most recent task that was run, ie. the top task.  Each `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo` has a property called `topActivity`.

```
public ComponentName topActivity
```

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html#topActivity): The activity component at the top of the history stack of the task. This is what the user is currently doing.

Answer (score 8):

try below code : you need to give proper permission

```
private String getCurrentTopActivity() {

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        return ar.topActivity.getClassName().toString();
    }
```

Comment: So in the Docs I see a big warning: Note: this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces. This should never be used for core logic in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based on the information found here. Such uses are not supported, and will likely break in the future. For example, if multiple applications can be actively running at the same time, assumptions made about the meaning of the data here for purposes of control flow will be incorrect. - does this maen I really shouldn't use this code?

Comment: this is giving me java.lang.SecurityException see here-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350328/global-class-to-register-listeners-for-all-the-activities-in-android