# Overriding onPause and onDestroy of com.android.settings.* activities

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause, ondestroy

Is it possible to override onPause and onDestroy methods of activity with com.android.settings.LanguageSettings class? All I wanna do is to fire an action when Language&Input setting screen is closed (I mean paused or destroyed). Here's my code so far.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");
startActivity(intent); // <--- I wanna detect this activity's paused or destroyed
```

As an alternative way, by starting the activity by startActivityForResult() and overriding onActivityResult(), I could detect user presses the back button and close the activity. However this doesn't work when the home button is pressed and the activity goes to background.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that ? You cannot since those activities are not written by you.

If you want to perform some action when the user changes the language at runtime, follow this article:

Handling Runtime Changes

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to kill/relaunch a background service so that the service is disabled while user's in language&input setting display. So the configuration change doesn't matter to my app.

Comment: My question is why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Ultimately speaking, because that's what my client wants. I know it's a bit weird but it makes sense thinking about what the app does.
Sorry, could you teach me if things in your article makes it possible to do what I want, or it can only detect configuration change?

Comment: Not sure if your client is technically sound to make design decisions. May be this would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131909/how-to-find-the-current-foreground-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restore data when the home button is pressed and the activity goes to background you can use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle)`

```
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
  bundle.putLong("myParam", valueOfMyParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but isn't this something should be put in the com.android.settings.LanguageSettings activity which I cannot override?