# Android - How to get last foreground activity on android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

I have an app which open different activity on different situation from response of server. Let i have two activity `Activity` **A** & `Activity` **B**. **A** or **B** can't be start at the same time. Let assume **A** activity is called to start and at the same time **B** is also called to start. If **A** is started first , **B** hide it and start on top of view making **A** in background. How can i check if **A** is already started from inside Activity **B** ??

tILL NOW WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList = m.getRunningTasks(10);
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) itr.next();
        int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
        CharSequence desc = runningTaskInfo.description;
        int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
        String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
        Constants.debugLog(TAG, "checkActivityStack desc: " + desc + " numOfActivities: " + numOfActivities + " topActivity: " + topActivity);
    }
```

=========================
aNOTHER ONE FROM STACK

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    int sizeStack =  am.getRunningTasks(5).size();

    for(int i = 0;i < sizeStack;i++){
        ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(2).get(i).topActivity;
        Constants.debugLog(TAG, "checkActivityStack "+cn.getClassName());
    }
```

Comment: take global variable and define that in application class, write it when activity A launch and check that variable in activity B

Comment: can you post your code, witch opening these activity?

Comment: or else you need to check into activitymanager's running processes

Comment: Actually my activities are started from different location as i start them from server response. That an exceptional rare issue which i am going to solve

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131909/how-to-find-the-current-foreground-activity-in-android

Comment: updated the question

Comment: i have call these code which are one a method from the current activity's onCreate method but i couldn't get the last foreground activity names from there

Answer (score 1):

I would probably make an public field, the code would look something like this:

```
// A
public static boolean started = false;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    started = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop():
    started = false;
}
```

And a check would look like this:

```
// B
if (A.started) {
    // Abort starting
}
```

Comment: actually i didn't wanted to do this way. If somehow i could get the name of the last foreground activity name it would be a great help for me

Comment: but if i don't find any solution i will surely use this way

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seemed pretty straightforward. 
http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2011/09/get-current-activity-and-package-name.html

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName() + "   Package Name :  " + componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

you need to use permission for android.permission.GET_TASKS
Hope this helps

Comment: this one return the name of my current top activity but i want the last one which is in background as the current one started

Comment: ok uneed to use am.getRunningTasks(10); for last 10 activity andr then use loop

Comment: Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
        int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
        CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
        String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
        int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
    }